# Amazon DynamoDB backup from a table and restore to a new table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database-administration

I am looking for a way to do below steps in Amazon DynamoDB:

> 1. backup the `table_A`
> 2. delete the `table_A`
> 3. create a new table with the same name `table_A`
> 4. fill the new table with the backup from step. 1

The purpose of this task is that I need to change the `LSI`(local secondary index) of `table_A`  The only way of changing it is to create a new table. right?  I also need to keep the data (it's no more than couple MBs)

So is it possible to do #3 and #4? Or is there any better approach of this whole thing?  If this table is in production, what would be a reasonable approach?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/backuprestore_HowItWorks.html

> Along with data, the following are also included (and can't be
>   excluded) on the backups:
>
> - Global secondary indexes (GSIs)
> - Local secondary indexes (LSIs)
> - Streams
> - Provisioned read and write capacity

Here is an approach I've used before:

1. Take a backup of `table_A` (this is just in case anything goes wrong)
2. Use Data Pipeline to extract the data in the DynamoDB table and put it in S3
3. Create a new table with your LSI, `table_B`
4. Load the data from S3 into `table_B` using Data Pipeline
5. Check everything is OK. Backup `table_B`
6. Delete `table_A`. Recreate it. Load the data in using Data Pipeline

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb.html

Data Pipeline is pretty rubbish in terms of usability and logging, but it works just fine.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and come back, appreciate for your help

Comment: I can confirm this "Data Pipeline is pretty rubbish in terms of usability and logging, but it works just fine."

Comment: Haha, hopefully they will improve it sometime. A lot of the AWS services outside of the core 4-5 products are actually pretty shoddy. They have a lot to do in the next few years!